# Converting sat_zenith_tn variable into geotiff file using R

Tags: r, geotiff-tiff, netcdf, sentinel-3

I am trying to convert .nc file to geotiff file of Sentinel-3 data product. However, I know there is dimension difference between coords and sat_zenith_tn.

and I got this error:-

> lst_warp = st_warp(lst, crs = "EPSG:4326", cellsize = 0.01, threshold
> = 0.02) Error in matrix(seq_len(prod(dims[dxy])), dims[dxy[1]], dims[dxy[2]])[xy] : subscript out of bounds In addition: Warning
> message: In transform_grid_grid(st_as_stars(src), st_dimensions(dest),
> threshold) : using Euclidean distance measures on geodetic coordinates

I used following R code...

```
library(stars)
library(sf)

path_name <- "E:/Sentinel3Work/New_Data/DesertRock/S3B_SL_2_LST____20220513T182418_20220513T182718_20220513T202947_0179_066_027_2340_PS2_O_NR_004.SEN3/S3B_SL_2_LST____20220513T182418_20220513T182718_20220513T202947_0179_066_027_2340_PS2_O_NR_004.SEN3"

#set directory
setwd(path_name)


nc_fileName <- "geometry_tn.nc"
file_variable <- "sat_zenith_tn"


output_fileName1 <- sub("\\..*", "", nc_fileName)
output_fileName <- paste0(file_variable, ".tif")
# Manually add projection information (modify the proj4string accordingly)
projection <- st_crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
# Read NetCDF file of geo reference
coords <- read_ncdf("geodetic_in.nc", var = c("latitude_in", "longitude_in"))
st_crs(coords) <- projection
lats <- coords$latitude_in
lons <- coords$longitude_in
lst <- read_ncdf(nc_fileName, var = file_variable)
st_crs(lst) <- projection

## for others
# lst <- lst$sat_zenith_tn
lst <- lst[[file_variable]]
lst <- st_as_stars(lst)
lst <- st_as_stars(lst, curvilinear = list(X1 = lons, X2 = lats))

lst_warp = st_warp(lst, crs = "EPSG:4326", cellsize = 0.01, threshold = 0.02)
write_stars(lst_warp, output_fileName)
```

Results:

> lst_warp = st_warp(lst, crs = "EPSG:4326", cellsize = 0.01, threshold
> = 0.02) Error in matrix(seq_len(prod(dims[dxy])), dims[dxy[1]], dims[dxy[2]])[xy] :    subscript out of bounds In addition: Warning
> message: In transform_grid_grid(st_as_stars(src), st_dimensions(dest),
> threshold) :   using Euclidean distance measures on geodetic
> coordinates